# To calculate average and unique number from a text file using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

**#To calculate average and unique value from a text file using pandas python**.

I am having a text file which is having two columns separated by "," and it is not having any column header. Column[0] has the taxi number and column[1] is having the number of km it had driven.

I want to calculate each taxi's how much km driven, how many times, and the average km driven by a taxi.

For example 00005 has driven 49 km, 3 times and the average is 16.33

```
00000,43
00001,43
00002,54
00000,43
00005,20
00004,15
00001,11
00005,8
00005,21
00004,5
```

I tried using
`df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[-1]].sum()` -  this is giving only sum
and  `df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[-1]].mean` - it is giving mean value but not average

Can someone please guide

Comment: Use `df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[-1]].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'count'])`

Comment: Thanks @mozway but for mean I am getting different value then average.

Comment: (arithmetic) mean and average are the same thing (unless you want to use an different mean? geometric? harmonic?)

Comment: Hi, @mozway is it possible to convert this code in the MapReduce program? Because of the huge data, I am thinking to use MapReduce.

Comment: I don't know, a wild guess for this kind of questions would be "yes" (I don't know the MapReduce program)

Comment: @mozway how to calculate this without using any library like "pandas".

Comment: why without libraries? is this an assignment?

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment.

Comment: Then you must provide your own, faithful, attempt. Otherwise this is asking us to do your homework for you ;)